# What authentication method uses an Auth header in the HTTP request?

Tags: php, authentication, curl, iis

I am connecting to Microsoft IIS server from a PHP script using cURL to send some JSON. Everything is working fine, but I don't know what type of authentication I am using.

This is the code:

```
$curlheader = array("Content-type: application/json", "Auth: N@0062Ibb$#=="); //"Auth:" is changed

$url = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:81/feed/ProdICCFeeds/"; //ip is also changed

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url); //set url
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true); //http POST
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $curlheader); //set header
$content = json_encode($aParamsArray); //set paameters, not here
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content); 
$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
```

What authentication system is that?

Comment: This isn't joepardy

Comment: yep, there is no prize, sorry... But i still would like to know.

Answer (score 0):

`Auth` is not  a [standard HTTP request header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields). You are not using a standard auth mechanism.